# Почему класс GzipStream сжимает слабее чем zip архиватор?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, gzip

Написал консольное приложение которое сжимает файлы с помощью класса GzipStream, сжимая 30гб формата .txt на выходе получаю файл размером в 222мб. При сжатии с помощью zip архиватора получаю 14мб. Вроде класс GzipStream и zip архиватор используют один и тот же алгоритм сжатия Deflate

Comment: Степень сжатия там и тут разная выбрана?

Comment: А размер буфера/словаря или что там у него - одинаковый?

Comment: В конструктор GzipStream передавал CompressionLevel.Optimal

Comment: Вообще, судя по всему, всё-таки этот метод предназначен для сжатия потока, я думаю, у архиватора, работающего с файлами, больше свободы в том плане, что он может попробовать разные методы сжатия, использовать большой буфер под словари, работать в два прохода и т.д. А сжатие потока предполагает только последовательный доступ к данным в один проход и наверняка с ограниченным буфером под словари.

Comment: @CrazyElf прогнал через свое приложение в 2 прохода получилось в 2 раза меньше чем через zip

Comment: @CrazyElf, а разве gzip и zip - это одно и то же?